# Evitar duplicados comprobando filas completas

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Me gustaría poder actualizar mi bbdd postgresql teniendo en cuenta si existe ya una fila o no.

Es decir, supongamos que tenemos dos columnas llamadas `nombre`, `valor`, y que yo inserto el la fila `naranjas`, 20.

```
| Nombre   | Valor |
|------------------|
| Naranjas | 20    |
```

Mi objetivo es que no se pueda subir otra vez el conjunto `naranjas, 20`, pero si que se pueda `limones, 20` o `naranjas, 21`.
He hecho varias pruebas, pero entiendo que esto se haría con `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT ... DO NOTHING`, ¿Es esto cierto? ¿O estoy muy equivocado?

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database = 'aaa',
    user     = 'bbb',
    password = 'ccc'
)
cursor = conn.cursor()


table = 'articulos'
cols  = '(descripcion, precio)'
data  = ("limones", 20)


query = f'''INSERT INTO articulos(descripcion, precio)
            VALUES (%s, %s)
            ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT articulos DO NOTHING;'''
cursor.execute(query, data)


conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

> UndefinedObject: no existe la restricción «articulos» para la tabla «articulos»

La duda viene, a que realmente no se si simplemente es un fallo de sintaxis o realmente estoy llendo por el camino equivocado.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Partiendo de que todo se puede resolver de varias formas, en mi opinión creo que es más natural usar los operadores `EXISTS` O `NOT EXISTS` https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/postgresqlya/temarios/descripcion.php?cod=221&punto=63&inicio=

Comment: ¿Pero la tabla tiene creada una restricción de inserción llamada `articulos`? ¿podrías agregar es script de creación de la misma?

Comment: Creo que no puedes tener un constraint con el mismo nombre de la tabla, nuevamente te digo: agrega el script de creación de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Te está faltando definir la `CONSTRAINT` para que el `ON CONFLICT` sepa por donde analizar, en tu caso pudiera ser una de tipo `UNIQUE`, por ejemplo:

```sql
ALTER TABLE articulos
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_articulos UNIQUE (Nombre, valor);
```

y entonces tu cógido SQL desde python debe usar el nombre de la `CONSTRAINT`:

```py
query = f'''INSERT INTO articulos(descripcion, precio)
            VALUES (%s, %s)
            ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_articulos DO NOTHING;'''
```